# ad-grid isn't displayed well

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular 4 project, based on [this starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter).

I'm trying to embed [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) in my project.

As for the first step, I followed [these instructions](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-angularcli/#gsc.tab=0) to create a new example project with ag-grid. It worked well and looked like this:

[image]

Then, I tried to embed it in my project, but it now looks like that:

[image]

I don't see any difference in the relevant code between the two projects, except I removed the "Red Component" stuff from my real project (but removing it from the example project doesn't corrupt the UI).

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
      <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"
                       [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>


constructor(
  ) {
    this.gridOptions = {};
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "ID",
        field: "id",
        width: 100
      },
      {
        headerName: "Value",
        field: "value",
        width: 100
      },

    ];
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [
      {id: 5, value: 10},
      {id: 10, value: 15},
      {id: 15, value: 20}
    ]
  }
```

I'd tried removing bootstrap but it didn't change anything.

I have no idea how to solve or investigate it, and any help will be profoundly appreciated. Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave both answers in case it helps anyone.

### Angular Starter

The [Github Readme](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/README.md#external-stylesheets) says you need a file in the `src/styles` folder, where you `@import` the other styles. Then you need to `import` this file in your `app.module.ts` file. Note that you may have to restart `npm run server`.

### Angular CLI

Add the following to `angular-cli.json`:

```
     "styles": [
         "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
         "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css"
     ],
```

**Remember to restart** `ng-serve` **after adding the styles**.

Comment: You see, I don't have any angular-cli.json file. As I said, I'm using an angular starter. You can see its source and you can see how the project is built.

Comment: Sorry, the CSS files should be placed in the `src/styles` folder, according to the starter Github Readme.

Comment: No change. I guess in the starter I also need to configure something in order to let angular / webpack / whaterver know about those files?!?

Comment: You restarted `npm run server`?

Comment: Yes, or more precisely I just started it because it was off.

Comment: Check the External Stylesheets section of the Readme, you also have to add some imports.

Comment: Great, it's working. I can't grant the bounty now, remind me in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

In your angular-cli.json file add the following

```js
{
"styles": [
         "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
         "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css"
     ],
     
     }
```